# beforeEach and AfterEach for every test case using Globals.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

So, I have a globals.js file where I have mentioned beforeEach and afterEach, but what I could understand from this link [Nightwatch Globals](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/using-nightwatch/global-setup-teardown.md), the beforeEach and afterEach are called once before and after a Test Suite (A single Js file). But in my framework I have multiple test cases in the a single js file (or Test Suite) and I want to call beforeEach and afterEach before and after every test case. Anyway to achieve that? Below is my globals.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    asyncHookTimeout: 40000,

    beforeEach: function (browser, done) {
        // browser.maximizeWindow();
        // browser.deleteCookies();
        browser.perform(function () {
            console.log('Inside BeforeEach');
            done();
        });
    }

    afterEach: function (browser, done) {
        browser.end(function () {
            console.log("Inside After Each");
            done();
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course there is! Just make use of the notorious Nightwatch [test hooks](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/using-nightwatch/test-hooks.md).

- If you want to filter your *test-suites*, then as you pointed out,
  we'll use the [global test
  hooks](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/using-nightwatch/global-setup-teardown.md).
- If you want to filter your *test-cases*, then we'll use the [test
  hooks](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/using-nightwatch/test-hooks.md)

**Example** (*your test-file should look like this*):

```
module.exports = {

  before(browser) {
    // > this will get run only ONCE, before all the tests <
  },
  beforeEach(browser) {
    // > this will get run before every test case <
  }

  tags: ['your', 'tags', 'go', 'here'],
  'Test Case No.1': (browser) => {
     // > this test does something here <
  },
  'Test Case No.2': (browser) => {
     // > this test does something else here <
  },
  'Test Case No.3': (browser) => {
     // > this test does something else here <
  },

  afterEach(browser) {
    // > this will get run after every test case <
  },
  after(browser) {
    // > this will get run ONCE, after all tests have run <
  }
};
```

**Lastly, quoting the DOCs:**

> The **before** and **after** will run before and after the execution of the
>   test suite respectively (*in our case, the test-file*), while **beforeEach** and **afterEach** are ran before
>   and after each test case (*test step*).

---

LE: What @AlapanDas wants is to custom-tailor the way the Nightwatch test-runner handles test-level hooks. This is of course doable, but dirty. You have to re-write the hooking logic from the following files:

**Nightwatch@v0.9.x:**

- **testcase.js** (path: `/nightwatch/lib/runner/testcase.js`);
- **testsuite.js** (path: `/nightwatch/lib/runner/testsuite.js`);

**Nightwatch@v1.0.x:**

- every **{hookName}.js** file from the `/hooks` folder (path: `/nightwatch/lib/testsuite/hooks/*.js`);

*Still, a compromise can be made here!* Just try to find the *common, recurring steps/instructions* from your `before`, `after`, etc. hooks and extract that logic inside a `/custom_commands` file. That would condense your test files, as well as decoupling the login from your hooks. On the long run, this will also grant the advantage of a *single-point-of-change* when maintaining the hooks.

Comment: Currently I am using it like the way you mentioned and this is kind of redundant. So was looking for some ways to implement it once and reusing it.

Comment: Hey @AlapanDas! Yeah, well, it is not redundant. They serve a very clear, specific purpose: *grant you access to test-level hooks*. No one will fault you for having them in all your test files (*assuming the logic if sound for the use of those hooks*).  So, **this is the recommended way to use test-level hooks**!

I'll updated the answer with what you have to try in order to achieve this, but trust me you'll get yourself into more trouble than you're ready for.

Comment: Hey @AlapanDas! What's the status on this? Did you decide to continue with the test file level hooks & extract common logic in `/custom_commands`? Let's bring this to a conclusion!

Comment: Not yet. Will give it a try after the holidays. Thanks for the help :)